# Chown for all users via sudors does not work for specific folder

Tags: permissions, git

I would like to allow chown for a special folder recursively for all users, so that I can use a git hook to automatically update the folder after a push.

For this I have customized sudoers using sudo visudo

```
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/chown -R git\:www-data /var/www/folder
```

in the hook I have entered the command as follows:

```
chown -R git:www-data /var/www/folder
```

When running the hook, the owner will be `git:git` when files are changed.
If then the `chown` command is executed then the following error message occurs:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/var/www/folder/changedfile.html': Operation not permitted
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `NOPASSWD` means that a password is not required, it does not mean that sudo is not required - is your hook command preceded by `sudo`?

Comment: The hook command is executed by the user git. It is not a member of sudo

I just added him to the group using `gpasswd -a git sudo`, but that didn't change anything. Still the same error message occurs

Comment: Regardless of group membership, you still need `sudo chown` rather than plain `chown`. BTW are you sure this is not something you could implement using setgid / sticky on the directory?